# Question about $\mathbb{N}$ failing to satisfy requirements for group classification

Tags: group-theory

I'm working a rather simple problem on whether the natural numbers satisfy the conditions for a group over the binary operations addition, subtraction, and/or multiplication. For the sake of consistency with the text's notation, I will exclude $0$ from the naturals, though I do think this actually makes a difference in terms of the final answer: for example, we would have an identity under addition and subtraction if $0$ were included, but the absence of $0$ means $\mathbb{N}$ no longer satisfies these properties.

With that said, my main confusion is in whether $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies the requirement of containing an inverse. Clearly, under multiplication, it does not, as, for example, the inverse of $2$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, which is a rational, but not a natural, number. Under addition, it seems that no such inverse would exist, as this element would be an integer, but not a natural. Subtraction is a bit confusing: the answer key states that this property does not hold. But, can't any natural number simply act as its own inverse?  For example, for any $x \in \mathbb{N}$, since we've excluded $0$ from the set, isn't $x - x = 0$, the identity?

So, I suppose my question boils down to this final bit on whether subtraction has an inverse in $\mathbb{N}$, assuming we exclude $0$, which obviously has no inverse, from $\mathbb{N}$. It's also very possible I'm defining the inverse incorrectly, as it seems that $e$ or $1$ are the most common representations and it varies by operation. (For example, I think we're aiming to find a product of $1$ with multiplication but a sum/difference of $0$ under addition and subtraction.)

Thanks.

Comment: is it that $1-2\in\Bbb N$?

Answer (score 3):

Subtraction is not even an operation in $\Bbb N$, whether or not $0$ is included.  There is no result to $1-2$, for example.  In the integers it is an operation, but $0$ is still not an identity.  It is true $a-0=a$, but you also need $0-a=a$ for $0$ to be an identity.  The integers do form a group under addition with $0$ as the identity.

Answer (score 1):

As Ross Millikan says, subtraction isn't an operation on the natural numbers, and in the integers it is an operation but lacks an inverse. It's worth noting that there is *yet another* way it fails to yield a group: subtraction is not associative. In general we have $(a-b)-c\not=a-(b-c)$; indeed, the two expressions are equal only when $c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If you exclude $0$ from natural numbers, then $\mathbb{N}$ has no identity element under addition (as you said). When an algebraic structure, namely a set with a binary operation, does not have an identity element talking about inverses becomes completely meaningless.

And as you figured out on your own, no element in $\mathbb{N}$ except $1$ has an inverse under multiplication. So, it's not a group under multiplication either.